# Excel Read Value with Formulas to Lookup Failing

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

```
Workbook SourceFile = oXLSrc.Workbooks.Open(Path.GetFileName(fileName), true);
TestSheet.get_Range("E33", Type.Missing);
```

The Sheet have a value and it's a ComboBox and data validation. This ComboBox values are coming from another worksheet. When I open the Excel in C#, ALL values are NULL. But when I open it in regular Excel it's working well and data is there. What am I missing?

Comment: So, cell `E33` contains a ComboBox?  I'm not concerned about the data validation, but I'm not sure what you're trying to get here. The value or formula in `E33`?  The contents of a ComboBox?  What does `TestSheet` look like?

Comment: What is TestSheet.get_range getting assigned to?

Answer (score 0):

Just based on your code above, you're not assigning the result of get_Range() to a variable. I expect to see something like...

```
 private Workbook m_Workbook; // The currently opened Excel file                
 ...    
 dynamic cellValue;     
 Worksheet sheet = null;

 try
 {
    sheet = (Worksheet)m_Workbook.Worksheets[0];
    cellValue = sheet.get_Range("E33").Value2;
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
 ...
```

Data validation or comboboxes should not factor into this.
For information on Text vs Value vs Value2, see https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/